# Kendo UI Mobile Button data-click firing twice

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, button, kendo-ui

I've been testing a simple (HTML5/jQuery) application that I made earlier where a user enters a message in a text box and when a button is clicked, this message is viewed as an alert.
The problem is that every time I click that button, the data-click attribute seems to be firing twice as the message is alerted twice.

I'm currently using Kendo UI version 2012.3.1114 along with jQuery 1.8.2
**I've also tried it with jQuery 1.8.3 and got the same results, but when using the older release of Kendo everything works fine

Can somebody help me please?!!!

Update:
Here is my code
**btw I'm using ripple emulator to test this app and even tried it on an iPad with the same results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <link href="styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="view" id="mainView">
    <br/>
    <center><a data-role="button" data-click="showAlert">Click Me</a></center>
    <br/>
</div>
<script>
    function showAlert(){
        alert("Clicked!!!");
    }
</script>
<script>
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a test page, something really simple with just a clickable element and an alert. Does it behave correctly? If not, then suspect the device. Otherwise, build up the page progressively until it breaks. Whatever you added last will be the culprit. Diagnosis complete. Now think about a fix.

Comment: I've been using KendoUI Mobile for a long time, ghost clicks usually happens if you don't use the data binding data-click.

I've tested your code, and it working properly.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/JSLHQ/1/

Please provide more details on how to reproduce your issue, like device or browser version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happening when use Kendo UI for MVC.
Within the Kendo UI Button Definition I have:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("showFirstGraphButton")
 .Tag("button")
 .Content("Submit Selection")
 .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "showFirstGraphButton" })
 .Events(ev => ev.Click("showFirstGraphButtonOnClick")))
```

And within the event handler function I wrote.

```
function showFirstGraphButtonOnClick(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.event.preventDefault(); 
.....  
}
```

And it worked for me, I did validate the form then just used jquery to submitted it if every validation went trough.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a simple mobile page. add a text box and button. on button click doing an alert of the textbox content. I did not get the alert twice. have a look at the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Events</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
    <script src="../../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
    <link href="../../../styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../../styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="../index.html">Back</a>
    <div data-role="view" id="button-events" data-title="Button Events">
        <input id="txtMessage" style="display: block; margin: 2em; text-align: center;width:280px"/>
        <a id="mobile-button3" data-click="showAlert" data-role="button" style="display: block; margin: 2em; text-align: center;">Show Alert</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        function showAlert(e) 
        {
            alert($("#txtMessage").val())
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        window.kendoMobileApplication = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you paste your code - so that we can debug that ?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but just for the sake of having an answer when someone comes looking. I ran into this same issues, and returning false in my function solved it for me.